# Selenium - element not found on only my machine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing

I'm running tests via Selenium for my project yet whenever I run them on my machine the test returns error not found. However when running on other peoples machines the tests run fine.

I've tried deleting and re-cloning the code and cleaning maven as well as updating the chrome driver.

I've tried deleting and re-cloning the code and cleaning maven as well as updating the chrome driver.

The code itself obviously isn't the issue as they've merged and run for everyone else on both main and branches.

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML and your code trials.

Comment: If the element not found is resolvable, rewrite the xpath or maintain two xpath of that element, which is throwing the element not found.                                           
            Ex- XPath=//*[@id=’FirstName’ or @name=’LastName’]